# MySQL CONCAT DOUBLE values in trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

**UPDATE**

The question needs clarity.

**I'm converting converting milliseconds to hours minutes seconds to create a date independent timestamp.**

Given time in milliseconds, I want the output to be a string in H:M:S
E.g.

```
9999999ms = 2.7777775 hrs
.7777775hrs * 60 = 46.66665 min
.66665min * 60 = 39.999sec
```

Desired output `02:46:39.999`

This has nothing to do with TIMESTAMP. It is a simple calculation followed by a string concatenation.

I'm having a frustrating time with the CONCATENATION. IT only returns hours and it does not ROUND the returned value.

```
DECLARE v_timestamp VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE v_hours DOUBLE(5,3);
DECLARE v_minutes DOUBLE(5,3);
DECLARE v_seconds DOUBLE(5,3);

SET v_hours = (NEW.amount_viewed_ms)/(3600000);
SET v_minutes = (v_hours - FLOOR(v_hours)) * 60;
SET v_seconds = (v_minutes - FLOOR(v_minutes)) * 60;

SET v_timestamp = CONCAT(ROUND(v_hours), ":", ROUND(v_minutes), ":", ROUND(v_seconds));
SET NEW.timestamp = v_timestamp;
```

I could use another pair of eyes to help figure out where this is going wrong.

Comment: Do you have an example you can share?

Comment: The example is the code I posted.

Comment: I don’t see any values in the question

Comment: Your actual goal seems to be to be do some calculations with timestamps? MySQL provides a lot of [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html), including e.g. [maketime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_maketime) to generate a time from hour/minute/second (which seems to be what you are trying to do using strings). If not, you may want to clarify your goal (and not the way you want to achieve it with).

Comment: No. I know about timestamps. The name is not the functionality.

Comment: I'm not trying to manipulate date time values.

Comment: Your question says 'values in a stored procedure.' - but you reference NEW.timestamp and NEW.amount_viewed_ms - NEW.values are only available in some triggers , so is this code in a trigger and what variety of trigger - why not include the trigger code or at least all the relevant parts?

Comment: P.Salmon, I don't know what you think is relevant. The trigger works fine. The problem is with the concat. Or just tell me what you need to see. Do you have some thoughts on the problem so far? If not don't waste your time it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see your problem simply increasing a couple of field sizes seems to produce a desired result without an example of NEW.amount_viewed_ms it's not possible to say more

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE P()
BEGIN
DECLARE v_timestamp VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE v_hours   double(20,3);
DECLARE v_minutes DOUBLE(5,3);
DECLARE v_seconds DOUBLE(5,3);

select (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE(NOW()), ' ', CURTIME(3))))/(3600000);

SET v_hours = (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE(NOW()), ' ', CURTIME(3))))/(3600000);
SET v_minutes = (v_hours - FLOOR(v_hours)) * 60;
SET v_seconds = (v_minutes - FLOOR(v_minutes)) * 60;

select v_hours,v_minutes,v_seconds, (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE(NOW()), ' ', CURTIME(3))))/(3600000);
SET v_timestamp = CONCAT(ROUND(v_hours), ":", ROUND(v_minutes), ":", ROUND(v_seconds));
select v_timestamp;


END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL P();

MariaDB [sandbox]> call p();
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE(NOW()), ' ', CURTIME(3))))/(3600000) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                      457.2335910 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)

+---------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| v_hours | v_minutes | v_seconds | (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE(NOW()), ' ', CURTIME(3))))/(3600000) |
+---------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 457.234 |    14.040 |     2.400 |                                                      457.2335910 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.025 sec)

+-------------+
| v_timestamp |
+-------------+
| 457:14:2    |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.032 sec)
```

Comment: Hmmm. Ok. Thanks. I will have to look at what you did here. For amount_viewed_ms just plug in any milliseconds value.

Comment: After looking this over carefully, it's not anywhere near what I'm trying to do. But it did help me understand my question is incomplete.